# EXCEL/VBA HELP ---- Is there a way to show a checkbox in excel based on another cells input?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, conditional-statements

If the cell A1 contains a value of A then a checkboxA will appear. If the cell A1 contains a value of B then a checkboxB will appear. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.We can help you more easily if you show the code you're working with. In general though, create code in the `Worksheet_Change` event Sub for that worksheet and detect any changes to your cell A1. If you get the value you're looking for, then for the checkbox in question you can toggle the visibility `.Visible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub ShowHide()
    With ActiveSheet
    Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case "A"
            .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = True
            .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = False
        Case "B"
            .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = False
            .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = True
        End Select
     End With
End Sub
```

If you want this to occur automatically when **A1** changes, then embed the logic in either a Calculate event macro or a Worksheet_Change macro.

For test purposes, I used this to create the boxes:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(171, 18, 72, 65.25).Select
    Selection.Name = "CheckboxA"

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(180, 81, 54, 54.75).Select
    Selection.Name = "CheckboxB"

End Sub
```